# vue-jstree does not open children when loading data via api

Tags: ajax, vue.js

```
   <v-jstree :data="data"
              textFieldName="name"
              @item-click="itemClick"
    />
```

If I use statics - then this works:

```
data() {
        return {
            data: [
                {
                    "name": "title 1",

                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Child 1",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Child 2",
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

        },
```

If I use ajax, then all data is loaded, but `openChildren` doesn't work(

Response comes in the correct format:

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "Title", "children": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Child 1" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Child 2" }.......
```

children are also loaded, why does the functionality break down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial, I found a way to solve it) in the server response in parent, the `"opened"` parameter must be specified , either **true** or **false**